# Algorithm to find secret cipher S-box in bin file

Tags: binary-analysis, encryption

Is there any algorithm that searches through binary file and detects existence of secret S-box built from look-up table (4 bit or 8 bit)? Consider the sbox is unavailable for public

The attached bin data is part of bin file obtained from compiling serpent cipher ( 6 s-boxes) with  uint 32 bit  array on mac os Mach-o file format. if you split the bin data you will find the values of all 6 s-boxes.

My point is lets consider a bin file you obtained and you do not know any thing about the cipher and location of its info in the bin file. The first thing in your search, you want to look for common things such as S-box or lfsr. 
I know that there is a plugin in IDA called findcrypt of common ciphers but iam looking for unknown cipher.

```
0d00 0000 0300 0000 0b00 0000 0000 0000
0a00 0000 0600 0000 0500 0000 0c00 0000
0100 0000 0e00 0000 0400 0000 0700 0000
0f00 0000 0900 0000 0800 0000 0200 0000
0500 0000 0800 0000 0200 0000 0e00 0000
0f00 0000 0600 0000 0c00 0000 0300 0000
0b00 0000 0400 0000 0700 0000 0900 0000
0100 0000 0d00 0000 0a00 0000 0000 0000
0c00 0000 0900 0000 0f00 0000 0400 0000
0b00 0000 0e00 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000
0000 0000 0300 0000 0600 0000 0d00 0000
0500 0000 0800 0000 0a00 0000 0700 0000
0000 0000 0900 0000 0a00 0000 0700 0000
0b00 0000 0e00 0000 0600 0000 0d00 0000
0300 0000 0500 0000 0c00 0000 0200 0000
0400 0000 0800 0000 0f00 0000 0100 0000
0500 0000 0000 0000 0800 0000 0300 0000
0a00 0000 0900 0000 0700 0000 0e00 0000
0200 0000 0c00 0000 0b00 0000 0600 0000
0400 0000 0f00 0000 0d00 0000 0100 0000
0800 0000 0f00 0000 0200 0000 0900 0000
0400 0000 0100 0000 0d00 0000 0e00 0000
0b00 0000 0600 0000 0500 0000 0300 0000
0700 0000 0c00 0000 0a00 0000 0000 0000
0f00 0000 0a00 0000 0100 0000 0d00 0000
0500 0000 0300 0000 0600 0000 0000 0000
0400 0000 0900 0000 0e00 0000 0700 0000
0200 0000 0c00 0000 0800 0000 0b00 0000
0300 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000 0d00 0000
0900 0000 0e00 0000 0f00 0000 0800 0000
0500 0000 0c00 0000 0b00 0000 0700 0000
0a00 0000 0100 0000 0400 0000 0200 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Could you provide some more details of, say, the file format you are looking at (e.g. ELF, PE) as well as the target environment in which the binary runs or is this not an executable but rather some kind of text file? As it stands your question is too broad and may get closed. You can always edit your own question and improve it and even if it gets closed you can vote to reopen it and others will have the chance to review your improvements.

Comment: thank you for the response, details are given in the question

Answer (score 1):

If I'd suspect existence of unknown encryption algorithm in the binary first thing I'd start with would be searching functions which contain too much shift and xor operations relatively to the function size.

From these functions I'd try to find s-boxes if there are any by data X-refs.

Comment: So far _this_ is more of a comment than an answer, though.